# What does a.sub_(lr*a.grad) actually do?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient, gradient-descent, fast-ai

I am doing the course of fast-ai, SGD and I can not understand.....

This subtracts the coefficients by (learning rate * gradient)...

But why is it necessary to subtract?

here is the code:

```
def update(): 
  y_hat = x@a  
  loss = mse(y_hat, y) 
  if t % 10 == 0: print (loss)
  loss.backward() 
  with torch.no_grad(): 
    a.sub_(lr * a.grad)
```

Comment: The gradient points to the direction of maximum increase, the opposite direction (minus gradient) points to the direction of maximum decrease. Its a mathematical property, not a programming thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Look at the image. It shows the loss function `J` as a function of the parameter `W`. Here it is a simplified representation with `W` being the only parameter. So, for a convex loss function, the curve looks as shown.

Note that the learning rate is positive. On the left side, the gradient (slope of the line tangent to the curve at that point) is negative, so the product of the learning rate and gradient is negative. Thus, subtracting the product from `W` will actually increase `W` (since 2 negatives make a positive). In this case, this is good because loss decreases.

On the other hand (on the right side), the gradient is positive, so the product of the learning rate and gradient is positive. Thus, subtracting the product from `W` reduces `W`. In this case also, this is good because the loss decreases.

We can extend this same thing for more number of parameters (the graph shown will be higher dimensional and won't be easy to visualize, which is why we had taken a single parameter `W` initially) and for other loss functions (even non-convex ones, though it won't always converge to the global minima, but definitely to the nearest local minima).

Note : This explanation can be found in Andrew Ng's courses of deeplearning.ai, but I couldn't find a direct link, so I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `a` represents your model parameters, based on `y_hat = x @  a`. This is necessary because the stochastic gradient descent algorithm aims to find a minima of the loss function. Therefore, you take the gradient w.r.t. your model parameters, and update them a little in the direction of the gradient.

Think of the analogy of sliding down a hill: if the landscape represents your loss, the gradient is the direction of steepest descent. To get to the bottom (i.e. minimize loss), you take little steps in the direction of the steepest descent from where you're standing.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, yes, by 'a' I mean the parameters.


I understand the hill analogy.

And I understand that to get to the bottom (less loss) you need to take small steps (not too small) to get to the bottom. 


even so ... I do not understand why we do 'update' in the direction of the gradient, by subtracting from.  a - (lr*gradient)    . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `sub` in `sub_` means subtract and `_` in `sub_` would change the parameter `a` inplace by subtracting the value of `lr* a.grad` (i.e. lr * gradient of loss w.r.t `a`) from `a`.

Suppose:
`a` = 3

`a.grad` = 1  # gradient of loss w.r.t. a

`lr` = 0.1

so, `a.sub_(lr*a.grad)` would inplace make the value of `a` as 2.9

whereas,

if you choose to do it like this:

`a` = `a`-`lr*a.grad`

then it assigns the value of "old" `a` into this "new" `a`.
This new  `a` might not have `requires_grad` to be True. So, you would then need to manually write this line `a.requires_grad_()` afterwards to be able to successfully implement gradient descent.